# Django subscriber feature

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a django site/platform where the main concept is users can create shops and other users can subscribe to those who have shops open (think Etsy). Trying to implement the subscriber feature and this is a model I have so far for it:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It works perfect for giving users the ability to subscribe and have the subscribtions listed in their profile and vice versa for shop owners, but for now a user can subscribe to a shop as many times as they want and I would like to prevent this. Idk if there is a constraint to allow multiple subscriber model instances by the same user but not allow for the same exact 'user' and 'sub_shop' instance OR if I am just going on about this in a very bad way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) to specify that the combination of `user` and `sub_shop` should be unique:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'sub_shop'],
                name='subscribe_once'
            )
        ]
```

prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can work with [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
# prior to Django-2.2
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'sub_shop']]
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful info